# How to make an acces point redirect all requests to one single page?

Tags: apache, redirect, webserver, raspberry-pi

My idea is that I basically wanna buy a Raspberry-Pi, put a webserver on it (Pi-Point or apache or cherokee, I don't really know what the best is) and let people connect to it, but redirect them to a page whatever their request is.

More or less like (here in Italy at least) hotels' WIFIs: you are free to connect, but you get redirected to a login page whatever address you put in the bar.

Is there any human way to do this?
And if so, what web server would be the best?

Answer (score 0):

You can search information on how tu build a [captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) on GNU/Linux

For example: http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Setting_up_a_captive_portal_from_scratch_using_Debian